# ModelSim simulation - modules not definied

Tags: simulation, verilog, modelsim

I tried to simulate verilog project (which uses some LPM modules) in ModelSim, but in spite of adding needed libraries I still had the error saying that the modules are not defined.
Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you telling Modelsim to search the libraries for you modules during elaboration?  For example you should pass the following arguments to vsim: `vsim -L lpm_ver` ...

Often pre-compiled Verilog libraries are suffixed "_ver" so make sure you are referencing the correct library.

Comment: I have both lpm and lpm_ver added.
[ModelSim screenshot](http://screenshooter.net/9441063/19_06_2014__17_28_19)

Comment: But are you passing the argument to to the `vsim` command?  Modelsim won't search all libraries by default, you have to tell it which ones to look in.